# Unusually High Requests on Azure App Config

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I've been building a Python app and have been managing everything in Azure. I use Azure App Config to store certain values and pull them throughout the code. I've noticed that my request counter jumps by around 100 just for starting the local debugger in VS code (not actually running any of my functions). I'm currently using the free version, so I am limited to 1,000 requests per day. Another example would be that adding a key-value pair to my configuration explorer counts as 5 requests. I use a class to pull all values from app config and store them there so I don't make a new request every time. Does anyone have any ideas as to why just running my local debugger would count as 100+ requests? Or why just manually adding a config key-value costs me 5 requests? My only thought is that the requests are measured by size, so manually adding a key-value would equate to 5 requests, but I'm not totally sure.

Here is an example config data class that I would instantiate once when the function is run:

```
class ConfigData:
def __init__(self):
    self.app_id = client.get_configuration_setting(key='app_id').value
    self.app_secret = client.get_configuration_setting(key='app_secret').value
    # Etc..
```

I would grab those values like this:

```
config = ConfigData()

app_id = config.app_id
app_secret = config.app_secret
```

Thanks,

Elijah

Answer (score 1):

Creating a key should only result in one request. It's worth noting that when the configuration explorer is opened that requests are sent out to populate the view. One request to list a page of key-values. One request to list the labels for each displayed key. So just opening the configuration explorer is 2 requests. Creating the key-value would be an extra request. So if you refreshed after creating the key-value that could've been where the 5 requests came from.

As far as 100 requests on startup, it looks like you are doing an individual client get for each setting. Each usage of the client is a single call to the service. To reduce the amount of requests you would need to get multiple key-values at once and then use the ones you need.